# Prove $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\lVert x^n\rVert^{\frac{1}{n}} = \inf_{n\geq 1}\{\lVert x^n\rVert^{\frac{1} {n}}\}$ by Fekete’s Lemma

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $A$ be a Banach algebra and suppose $a \in A$,  I'd like to prove

> $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\lVert x^n\rVert^{\frac{1}{n}} = \inf_{n\geq 
> 1}\{\lVert x^n\rVert^{\frac{1} {n}}\}$

by Fekete's Lemma, so at first, I'll mention this lemma as following

> let $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $$a_{m+n}\leq a_m+a_n $$ for all $m, n\in \Bbb{N}$ if the sequence  $(\frac{a_n}{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded below, then $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n} = \inf_{n\geq 
> 1}(\frac{a_n}{n})$$

any help would gratly be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Let $a_n = \ln \|x^n\|$. We have $\|x^{n+m}\| \leq \|x^n\| \|x\|^m$ which implies $a_{n+m} \leq a_n + a_m$. In other hand, we have 
$$\|x^n\| \geq \sup\{|\lambda|\,:\, \lambda \in Spect(x^n)\} = (\sup\{|\lambda|\, :\, \lambda \in Spect(x)\})^n,$$
hence $\frac{a_n}n$ is bounded from below. By Feteke's lemma, we get
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}n = \inf_{n\geq 1} \frac{a_n}n,$$
which implies 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \|x^n\|^{\frac1n} = \inf_{n\geq 1} \|x^n\|^{\frac1n}.$$

Comment: @Dear nguyen0610m please explain a bit more the last equality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fisrt, notice that your statement is obviously true if $x =0$.

So suppose $x \neq 0$ and study $a_n = \ln \left\| x^n \right\|$. You have
$$a_{n+m} = \ln \left\| x^{n+m} \right\| \leq \ln \left( \left\| x^n \right\| \left\| x^m \right\| \right) = \ln \left\| x^n \right\| + \ln \left\| x^m \right\| = a_n + a_m$$

So you know, by what you call Fekete's lemma, that
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{a_n}{n} = \inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*} \frac{a_n}{n}$$

(actually, this lemma is satisfied also in the case where $(a_n/n)$ is now bounded below and you authorize the limit/inf to be $-\infty$)

You deduce that 
$$e^{\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{a_n}{n}} = e^{\inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*} \frac{a_n}{n}}$$

so $$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} e^{\frac{\ln \left\| x^n \right\|}{n}} = \inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*} e^{\frac{\ln \left\| x^n \right\|}{n}}$$

i.e.
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \left\| x^n \right\| ^{\frac{1}{n}} = \inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*}  \left\| x^n \right\| ^{\frac{1}{n}} $$

Comment: $$e^{\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{a_n}{n}} = e^{\inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*} \frac{a_n}{n}}$$
@Thanks how did you deduce
 $$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} e^{\frac{\ln \left\| x^n \right\|}{n}} = \inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*} e^{\frac{\ln \left\| x^n \right\|}{n}}$$

Comment: Especially right hand

Comment: $x \rightarrow e^x$ is a bijection betwenn the lowers bounds of $\lbrace \frac{a_n}{n} \rbrace$ and the lower bounds of $\lbrace e^{\frac{a_n}{n}} \rbrace$. Because $\exp$ is increasing, you deduce that the image by $\exp$ of the greatest lower bound of the first set is equal to the greatest lower bound of the second set.